# Teradata Rows to Columns (Need to Merge Doubled Row Count)

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata, transpose, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a query I'm running as follows -

```
SELECT 
item1,
item2,
item3,
CASE WHEN item4 = 'type A' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT field) END AS dcount_field_A,
CASE WHEN item4 = 'type B' THEN COUNT(DISTINCT field) END AS dcount_field_B,
FROM table
GROUP BY
item1
item2
item3
item4
```

and my output is:

| Item1 | Item2 | Item 3 | dcount_field_B | dcount_field_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1Value1 | Item2Value1 | Item3Value1 | NULL | 1234 |
| Item1Value1 | Item2Value1 | Item3Value1 | 1234 | NULL |

but what I *need* is for these rows to be merged, like:

| Item1 | Item2 | Item 3 | dcount_field_B | dcount_field_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1Value1 | Item2Value1 | Item3Value1 | 1234 | 1234 |

**Other attempted adjustments:**

- removing item4 from the group by gives me an error *"Selected
  non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."*
- PIVOT is not an option in my version of teradata
- I have also tried a subquery of

```
    (SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN item4 = 'type A' THEN field END)) AS dcount_field_A,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN item4 = 'type B' THEN field END)) AS dcount_field_B
    FROM table
    GROUP BY item4),
```

> and I get the error *"Too many expressions in the select list of a subquery."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation.  With `count(distinct)` this looks like:

```
SELECT item1, item2, item3,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN item4 = 'type A' THEN field END) AS dcount_field_A,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN item4 = 'type B' THEN field END) AS dcount_field_B,
FROM table
GROUP BY item1, item2, item3;
```